# BASH and PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, zip

I am interested in embedding bash and python scripts. The basic idea is that the output from my bash commands serve as input to python.

I have a set of zip files that I want to reduce the size by selecting a chunk of data. The fact is that bash can unzip and can process large file much faster than python.

```
channel="Channel_08"
channelafter="Channel_10"
source=/Home/linux/test/*.zip  
destination=/home/linux/test2 

for file in $source
do filename=$(basename $file); eval "head -\$((\$(unzip -c \$file | grep -n \$channelafter |cut -f1,1 -d':')-8)) <(unzip -c \$file)|tail -\$((\$(unzip -c \$file | grep -n \$channelafter |cut -f1,1 -d':')-\$(unzip -c \$file|grep -n \$channel |cut -f1,1 -d':')))" > $destination/"$filename".txt; echo "$filename".txt
done
```

The resulting files have much less size and only have the selected data from channel to channel_after.

Now, I need to run a python script that instead of writing the output to > `$destination/"$filename".txt` I can use it to read and process the data. This script will be runned every day automaticaly with DAEMON

```
class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stdin_path = '/dev/null'
        self.stdout_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.stderr_path = '/dev/tty'
        self.pidfile_path =  '/tmp/foo.pid'
        self.pidfile_timeout = 5
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
            #print(process.memory_info().rss)
            routine()
            print("Running")
            time.sleep(3600*24)
def routine(): 

for line in $filename:
    df.iloc[count] = line
    count +=1
```

Please bear in mind that my python is installed on windows, but I still need to run the bash commands.

Comment: *" bash can unzip  and can process large file much faster than python*" - Bash has no unzip capability, it is the external `unzip` program which does that.  So far as I can see you are not using any bash I/O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn about the [pipe symbol](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html) in shell programming. Just like on the command line, you can chain commands with | such that the output of the left hand side is received as input on the right hand side.

So instead of redirecting `> $destination/"$filename".txt`, you can `| /path/to/python-script.py`.

Now whatever is sent to stdout by the left part can be read from stdin on the right side. Depending on what you have on the right (it can be an executable program or a script), you may have specific ways to tell it to read from stdin.

Comment: But I want to combine everything into my python script . Could that be?

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess
filenames = subprocess.check_output("./shellscript.sh", shell=True).decode()  # Decode to convert bytes to str
filenames = filenames.split('\n')  # or whatever the splitter eg. space.
for line in filenames:
# your logic
```

Comment: CalledProcessError: Command './script.sh' returned non-zero exit status 1. Why is that?

Comment: It is a problem with your shell script; this means your shell script doesn't run successfully, try to run it individually and see if it exits with zero `echo $?` after running the script from the terminal